# Python: 2D wireframe plot from predefined triangles

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, gis, mesh

What is the best way to plot, as a wireframe, existing triangles using Python?

To clarify:

I have two sets of data: one contains pairs of X, Y coordinates, and the other is the output of an algorithm mapping these points to an 'ideal' (Delaunay) mesh.

For example, consider the X, Y pairs::

```
  #X Y
1 330822.25 4310194.75
2 330827.25 4310194.75
3 330832.25 4310194.75
4 330837.25 4310194.75
5 330842.25 4310194.75
6 330847.25 4310194.75
...
```

And the algorithm output:

```
    1717        1761        1762
    1718        1717        1762
    1718        1673        1717
    1718        1674        1673
    1673        1674        1629
    1629        1674        1630
```

where X, Y pair #1717 forms a triangle with X, Y pair #1761 and #1762.

In other words, the first line of the Delaunay algorithm output can be represented as:

```
    (331037.25 4310004.75)        (331037.25 4309999.75)        (330822.25 4309994.75)
```

and this forms a single triangle. After mapping the two data sets into something similar to the above set of three tuples, I would like to plot every triangle present within these lines.

Any suggestions? Bonus points if this can be extended to 3D!

Comment: Check plt.triplot [http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/triplot_demo.html](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/triplot_demo.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may skip the step of manually calculating the Delaunay triangulation and let matplotlib take care of it. This is done using [`triplot`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.triplot.html).

```
plt.triplot(x, y)
```

where `x` and `y` are the two columns from your initial data.

In case you really want to use your own algorithm, you can put your indizes into `plt.triplot` using the third argument `triangles`.

```
plt.triplot(x, y, triangles=triangles)
```

where triangles is the `(N, 3)` array of indizes.

A [complete example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/triplot_demo.html) can be found on the matplotlib page.

Comment: This is *perfect*. Thank you!